# JQuery Ajax request recieves <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: jquery, ajax, response

I am sending a piece of date to the same document and everything works fine until I want to compare the response value with a string. So here is my JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : 'html',
            cache: false,
            data: {serienummer: serial},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if ('success' == response){
                    //Do something
                } else {
                   //Do something else
                }
                },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert('error: ' + error);
            }
        });
```

I post the data to the same page and compare it with the data in my database and return "success" if there is a comparision or return "error" if there is not.

But if I console.log() the response I get the following:

```
success<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why is this not just 'success' or 'error'? How can I solve this to compare the response? Has it something to do with the dataType?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are posting the page to itself and get the HTML back from the page you are on. You need to create an `if (isSet($_POST)) { echo "success"; exit(); } ?><!DOCTYPE...>` that returns the string "success" just for that call OR create another php: `$.ajax({ url="someprocess.php",`

Comment: Yup, actually it is just a part of PHP code. So I am echoing the result

Comment: Exit(); did the job! Now it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exit(); at the end of the PHP code that processes everything did the job! I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

that is because you havent 
please specify url in your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: "data to be post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.d);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: even without url it is working. Only the result is not what I expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

you can add status to success function like this:

```
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
```

more info here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-textstatus-documented

Answer (score 0):

In that ajax call you can set **dataType : 'html'** remove its and try its.
you can set **datatype : html** so that reason you can get response like this `success<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

Converting to answer

You are posting the page to itself and get the HTML back from the page you are on. You need to add an exit or wrap the html in else

```
if (isSet($_POST)) { echo "success"; exit(); } ?>
<!DOCTYPE...>
```

that returns the string "success" just for that call OR create another php:

```
$.ajax({ url="someprocess.php"
```